# Is it okay to store composable values as static variables?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I have a function `initUtils()` which is composable. It's saving stuff like `LocalDensity.current` in static fields for non composable use. For example, create extension function like `Int.px` for selecting the size in pixels (like xml did).

Comment: What is the point in doing this? For example, the current density is just a lookup, so you aren’t saving performance by trying to “lazy load” the value. Also, it’s not necessarily a constant if the user changes displays.

Comment: You can also save things like global context for creating static toasts as variables, for example

Comment: It would make more sense to do this in your Application class's `onCreate` since that is the entry point of your app. Then your value doesn't have to be lazy loaded and you know it's safe to use at any time. And you won't risk leaking an Activity as a Context.